# Restrict user input in form without restricting data shown

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a field `Status`, which is a field in the form's record source table; it is a lookup field based on the table `StatusType`.  I want to display the existing contents of the table, but only allow users to enter `Status` entries that, e.g., start with "X".  I tried setting the Row Source for the control to:

```
select Status from StatusType where left(Status,1)="X"
```

But this resulted in the form displaying a blank in the `Status` field for records where that field doesn't start with "X".  I want these data items to be displayed in the form, I just don't want them to be options in the form's `Status` drop-down.  How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `BeforeUpdate` to check the user's input and cancel the change if it would violate my validation rule:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If Not CheckValid(Me.Status.Value) Then
 Cancel = 1
 MsgBox "You must enter a valid status."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change to

```
select Status from StatusType where Mid(Status,1,1)="X"
```

Comment: The problem isn't which query I'm using to get the Row Source.  It's that when I set this as the row source, any item in that column that isn't found in the query results shows up as blank, and I want the actual data values for those items to show up.